# PHP Session not working immediately however works after refreshing the page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Session not working:

On-Page 1, I am getting Client ID using the form and redirecting the user to auth.marketingcloudapis.com for validation which then redirects to "https%3A%2F%2Fpharmtechsonly.com%2Fwebform%2Fcollect" which is my page 2.

**Page 1 :**

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();


if(isset($_POST['webform']))
{
  
$Client_ID = $_POST['Client_ID'];  
    $YOUR_SUBDOMAIN = $_POST['YOUR_SUBDOMAIN'];
    $_SESSION["Client_ID"] = $_POST['YOUR_SUBDOMAIN'];
    $_SESSION["YOUR_SUBDOMAIN"] = $_POST['YOUR_SUBDOMAIN'];
    
    
 $redirect = "https://".$YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=".$Client_ID."&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpharmtechsonly.com%2Fwebform%2Fcollect%2Dcode&scope=email_read%20email_write%20email_send&state=mystate";
 
 
 
    header("Location: $redirect");
    session_write_close();
exit();
 
}
 ?>
 


 
<form action="" method="post">
  Client ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Client_ID">
  <br>
    YOUR SUBDOMAIN:<br>
  <input type="text" name="YOUR_SUBDOMAIN">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="webform" value="Authorize">
</form> 



</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2 :**

```html
<?php

session_start();

$Client_ID = $_SESSION["Client_ID"];

echo $Client_ID;
?>
```

I am simply echoing $_SESSION["Client_ID"] which does not work immediatly when I reach page 2, however works when I hit refresh.

Comment: I noticed that you say it redirects, but it will not. You have output before the header, and that generates an error. (Never start your script with `<html>`, that belongs at the end after all php is done.)  What’s really happening? Also why does client id get assigned your subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning  `$_POST['YOUR_SUBDOMAIN']`
 to `$_SESSION['Client_ID']` 
 instead of `$Client_ID`

Comment: In the first step I did that: $Client_ID = $_POST['Client_ID'];

Comment: But then you're not assigning it to the session var

Comment: I have tried changing this :


    $_SESSION["Client_ID"] = $_POST['YOUR_SUBDOMAIN'];


to this:
    
$_SESSION["Client_ID"] = $Client_ID;

Comment: I have also tried doing the same with cookies. There also when I reach page 2, I do not see the client ID but as soon as I hit refresh, client ID echos.